# How to use Salesforce Private Connect for a European Salesforce Org

Tags: callout

Salesforce Private Connect allows a completely private connection to be established between a Salesforce Org and AWS.

I was trying to configure it between my Europe-based Salesforce Org and a London AWS region, but I've run into the following issue:

When configuring the Private Connect in Salesforce, there are no available options in the AWS regions list. Presumably because the only Salesforce-managed AWS VPCs are in US regions and so are only available for Salesforce Orgs that use the North America data centers.

The documentation does say:

> The AWS Regions dropdown in the Private Connect Setup page shows only the regions that your Salesforce org can access. If you don’t see your VPC region in the dropdown, you can peer your existing VPC to an available region that shows in the dropdown. You can also create a VPC inside an available region before creating a connection.

But, if I am getting no options in the AWS Regions dropdown, I can't get the service name and IAM role that I need to provide the AWS developers to set up their connection between their VPC and the Salesforce-managed VPCs.

Does anyone know how to connect from a European Salesforce Org using Salesforce Private Connect, or how to get hold of the service names for the Salesforce-managed VPCs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not available yet for European orgs. The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.private_connect_considerations.htm&type=5) mentions that only orgs running in NA Data centers have this service, not written clearly though.

> Data centers: North America.

The SF blog [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/10/using-private-connect-to-securely-connect-data-between-salesforce-and-aws.html) does mention that

> Salesforce Private Connect will be generally available as part of the
> Summer ’20 release in July for North American orgs.

---

> The AWS Regions dropdown in the Private Connect Setup page shows only
> the regions that your Salesforce org can access. If you don’t see your
> VPC region in the dropdown, you can peer your existing VPC to an
> available region that shows in the dropdown. You can also create a VPC
> inside an available region before creating a connection.

This means that the orgs in NA can access `us-east-1` and `us-west-2` regions only, if you want to access other regions, you need to connect the other regions to either of these 2 regions via peering.

There has been only 2 updates on Private connect after Summer 20,

- It became HIPAA compliant
- You can see source IP addresses allocated to your inbound network connection.

No more available/data centre updates.

Comment: Thanks Manjit. I did read those docs and the blog but, as you say, they are very vague. Regarding peering a VPC in one AWS with another, I saw that but I can't see how that helps. If we can't connect an EMEA Salesforce Org with a Salesforce-managed VPC in `us-east-1` or `us-west-1`, then it doesn't help us if we can peer our VPCs in AWS to access the Salesforce-managed AWS VPCs. We first need to get access to the Salesforce-managed VPCs from Salesforce, but can't because they are not given as an option when configuring Private Connect. Grrr... so frustrating. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It won't help the EMEA orgs as it is not available outside NA data centers of SF but it would help the NA SF orgs. NA orgs don't have access to all AWS regions, only 2 are available. If they want to connect to other regions of AWS, they can use peering. The Private connect offering is not expanded to EMEA data centers, once it is, you should be able to do it.

Comment: Yes for sure. Very helpful. Thanks Manjit.

Comment: Apparently Private Connect will be delivered for EMEA in Q3 or Q4 of 2021.

Comment: That's great news!